# GLSL shader detechment

Tags: opengl, glsl

i am trying to add GLSL shader and i am successfully added that to get per fragment lighting,
 but can it possible to detach shader dynamically from geometry and getting the OpenGL basic    effects for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use 2 different programs (one with and one without per fragment lighting) and swap between them

or create a uniform boolean that will disable perfragment lighting in the shader